# To what extent is music permissible?

Tags: music

I am a convert who has stumbled upon the hadith you find hereunder. Being an avid fan of listening to music and playing the guitar myself, I seek to understand the ruling regarding music: what is permissible? Is music haram or makruh?

Thank you for your time should you answer this question!

“Bukhari, Volume 7, Book 69, Number 494v: Narrated Abu ‘Amir or Abu Malik Al-Ash’ari: that he heard the Prophet saying, “From among my followers there will be some people who will consider illegal sexual intercourse, the wearing of silk, the drinking of alcoholic drinks and the use of musical instruments, as lawful. And there will be some people who will stay near the side of a mountain and in the evening their shepherd will come to them with their sheep and ask them for something, but they will say to him, ‘Return to us tomorrow.’ Allah will destroy them during the night and will let the mountain fall on them, and He will transform the rest of them into monkeys and pigs and they will remain so till the Day of Resurrection.”

Answer (score -1):

First know the history, how music was created

[The Story of Sheeth (AS) - Music & Adultery Begins](https://youtu.be/ee6qv9oOkyA)

Music is Haram, it's from Shaytaan.
Music and Qur'an can't stay in One Heart.